# How do I remove the entire left nav bar in admin for certain level users?

Tags: plugins, admin, admin-menu

I know how to remove items from the left nav bar (hook into `admin_menu` and do `global $menu; unset( $menu[ __( "Posts" ) ] );` for example). But it still shows a left nav bar (with nothing on it). I want the entire left nav bar gone.

I have tried this and it doesn't work:

```
//This doesn't work (in any hook, or plugin constructor)
show_admin_bar(false);

//This also doesn't work
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

What is the hook/function to do this?

Comment: It is a security topic? If no, hide it via Javascript - `jQuery('#adminmenuback, #adminmenuwrap').remove();`

Comment: @bueltge I would prefer a way to keep it from being written to the page.

Comment: Which page, in your question was the goal to remove the completely menu on the left side?

Comment: @bueltge Every admin page if the user is an editor. I don't want them to have any left navigation.

Comment: Maybe you can explain your requirements, your goal. I think, I understand not right. Do you remove items in the menu, right? And now you have items, there should also remove?

Comment: @bueltge Here's what I mean: I have removed **all** items from the left side nav. That includes "Plugins" Menu link, "Dashboard" link, "Pages" link, etc. They're all gone. Now, I'm left with an empty vertical dark-gray bar on the left side of the admin page. I want that gone. I can remove it with CSS, but I would prefer a "cleaner" server-side removal.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot, much helpful and easy to understand? Do you have also remove the `Separator` element?

Answer (score 0):

You could creatively use output caching to capture the adminbar and then discard it like so:

```
<?php
// this filter runs in menu-header.php L37 right before the admin menu is rendered
add_filter( 'parent_file', function( $parent_file ){
    ob_start();
    return $parent_file;
} );
// runs after the output
add_action( 'in_admin_header', function(){
    ob_clean(); // discard output
    echo '<div id="wpcontent">'; 
} );
```

Please do not actually consider using this in any production environment. It does not provide any security and it might break various things (for example the admin toolbar). I consider this an educational answer to the problem "how to use PHP output caching and WP filters to move remove stuff?". You are probably better off just using CSS.

Comment: Thank you for the idea but that's not really (as you state) a production-level concept. It could also be a bottleneck on RAM.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the bottom of the `menu-header.php` file in the `wp-admin` folder, you will see that the admin menu is hard coded. There are no hooks that would allow you to disable it.

Another issue is that the `#wpcontent` div has a left margin (depending on the screen size), so even if you did strip out the admin menu code, the space it normally occupies would still be there.

Comment: Since the sidebar is hardcoded, OP's best shot at removing it might be to do it client side with JS.